# How to prove that a function is left continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

I cannot work out this problem even though it seems not that difficult. Could anyone kindly give me any hint? Thanks!

If $f(x)$ is measurable on $E \subset \mathbb R$, then 
$$ 
\varphi (t)=m\big(\{x \in E : f(x) \lt t\}\big)
$$ 
is a left continuous function on $\mathbb R$.

I first picked a sequence $\{t_n\}$ converging to $t$.

But I cannot prove that
$$ 
\lim_{t_n \nearrow t} \,m\big(\{x \in E : f(x) \lt t_n\}\big)=m\big(\{x \in E : f(x) \lt t\}\big).
$$

Comment: Hint: You should consider a sequence which converges upwards.

Comment: yet shouldn't we choose an ordinary sequence instead of an upward one? @user161825

Comment: Then you're showing continuity, not left continuity.

Comment: yeah, what I mean is to take a sequence converging to on the left of t but this sequence is not necessarily upward. I think it is doable right? @user161825

Comment: If you mean an ordinary sequence $t_n< t$, then you can show that $\phi(t_n)\rightarrow \phi(t)$ for all such sequences if and only if $\phi(t_n)\rightarrow \phi(t)$ for all increasing sequences. Hint: When showing the non-trivial direction, go for a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

For any $t$, let $S_t:=\{x\in E|f(x)<t\}$, and note that whenever $(t_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence that converges to $t$ we have $S_t=\bigcup_nS_{t_n}$, thus $$m(S_t)=m\left(\bigcup_nS_{t_n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(S_{t_n}),$$and left continuity follows.

Comment: Thanks, @Amitai, that's very clear! I got myself stuck believing that I should only take an ordinary sequence instead of any other with some fancy properties...but using suplim and inflim only made me more perplexed...

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is left continuous at $t_0$ means: If $t_n\to t_0$ and $t_n<t_0$, then $g(t_n)\to g(t_0)$. In fact, we can assume that $\{t_n\}$ is strictly increasing.

In our case,
$$
\{x\in E: f(x)<t_0\}=\{x\in E: f(x)<t_1\}\cup\{x\in E: t_1\le f(x)<t_2\}\cup\cdots\cup
\{x\in E: t_n\le f(x)<t_{n+1}\}\cup\cdots=\{x\in E: f(x)<t_1\}\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty
\{x\in E: t_n\le f(x)<t_{n+1}\}
$$
and all the sets
$$
\{x\in E: f(x)<t_1\},\,
\{x\in E: t_n\le f(x)<t_{n+1}\}, \quad n\in\mathbb N,
$$
are measurable and disjoint. Thus

$$
g(t_0)=m\left(\{x\in E: f(x)<t_0\}\right)=m\left(\{x\in E: f(x)<t_1\}\right)
+\sum_{n=1}^\infty m\left(\{x\in E: t_n \le f(x)<t_{n+1}\}\right) \\
=m\left(\{x\in E: f(x)<t_1\}\right)
+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n m\left(\{x\in E: t_k\le f(x)<t_{k+1}\}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}
m\left(\{x\in E: f(x)<t_{n+1}\}\right)=\lim_{n\in\infty} g(t_{n+1}).
$$

Comment: @drhab - Corrected it. Thanks.